# Detection of concurrent event appearances - pandas and DataFrame, but possibly pure-python related

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the fastest and most elegant solution to the situation described below.

I have a large DataFrame which contains the record of some machine states. 
For this example let's assume we have only two machines: `one` and `two` (in reality I've got much more, but this shouldn't matter). Every machine can be in one of two states: `up` and `down`.

Here is how an example record can be created:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : range(8),
'machine' : ["one","one","two","two","one","two","two","one"],
'status' : ["up","down","up","down","up","up","down","down"]})
```

and how it looks like:

```
time    machine status
0       one     up
1       one     down
2       two     up
3       two     down
4       one     up
5       two     up
6       two     down
7       one     down
```

The records are strictly ordered (in reality by timestamps).

Now, **what I want to achieve** is to find situations, where both machines were in a high state (`up`), and preferably return a subset of the DataFrame, showing such situations. In the example above, a subset between time `5` and `6` is interesting for me, as both `one` and `two` machines were in `up` state at that time.

The *brute force* solution would be probably to go through the data frame and store the state of all machines in a list, checking if we have two of them in an `up` state during every iteration, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

All suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started, how about something like

```
df2 = df.pivot(index="time", columns="machine", values="status")
df2 = df2.fillna(method='ffill')
both_up = df2[(df2 == "up").all(axis=1)]
```

which produces

```
>>> both_up
machine one two
time           
5        up  up
```

given your example.

---

First, build the initial `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : range(8),
'machine' : ["one","one","two","two","one","two","two","one"],
'status' : ["up","down","up","down","up","up","down","down"]})
>>> df
  machine status  time
0     one     up     0
1     one   down     1
2     two     up     2
3     two   down     3
4     one     up     4
5     two     up     5
6     two   down     6
7     one   down     7
```

Then pivot:

```
>>> df2 = df.pivot(index="time", columns="machine", values="status")
>>> df2
machine   one   two
time               
0          up   NaN
1        down   NaN
2         NaN    up
3         NaN  down
4          up   NaN
5         NaN    up
6         NaN  down
7        down   NaN
```

We don't know anything about the state of machine two before time 2 -- unless we assume that only transitions are recorded and not states, so it must have been down before -- but the other missing states we can guess assuming all the relevant changes are caught.  IOW, we can forward-fill:

```
>>> df2 = df2.fillna(method='ffill')
>>> df2
machine   one   two
time               
0          up   NaN
1        down   NaN
2        down    up
3        down  down
4          up  down
5          up    up
6          up  down
7        down  down
```

And then we can look for the places where they're both up:

```
>>> (df2 == "up").all(axis=1)
time
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
5        True
6       False
7       False
dtype: bool
>>> both_up = df2[(df2 == "up").all(axis=1)]
>>> both_up
machine one two
time           
5        up  up
```

With just a little more effort you could get `[5,6)` or some duration measure out of it but hopefully the above will help you get started.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, this is what I was looking for. I need to adapt this a bit to my real needs, but the idea is really clever and simple.